# vim very slow to start

Tags: vim, freebsd, x11-forwarding

> OS == FreeBSD-12.1p2
>   Vim == 8.1.2372

I am encountering a problem with vim having an excessively slow startup time on just one system.  The content of `vim --startuptime vim_startuptime.log` follows:

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.030  000.030: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.166  000.136: Allocated generic buffers
000.293  000.127: locale set
000.307  000.014: GUI prepared
000.309  000.002: clipboard setup
000.334  000.025: window checked
001.000  000.666: inits 1
001.064  000.064: parsing arguments
001.066  000.002: expanding arguments
001.136  000.070: shell init
001.795  000.659: Termcap init
001.846  000.051: inits 2
002.060  000.214: init highlight
003.900  001.183  001.183: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
. . .
018.890  001.561: loading plugins
018.997  000.107: loading packages
019.028  000.031: loading after plugins
019.077  000.049: inits 3
019.197  000.120: reading viminfo
75047.076  75027.879: setup clipboard
75047.146  000.070: setting raw mode
75047.161  000.015: start termcap
75047.191  000.030: clearing screen
75047.457  000.266: opening buffers
75047.551  000.094: BufEnter autocommands
75047.555  000.004: editing files in windows
75047.741  000.186: VimEnter autocommands
75047.744  000.003: before starting main loop
75048.149  000.405: first screen update
75048.151  000.002: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

However, if I disable X then this is the result (`vim -X --startuptime vim_startuptime-X.log`):

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.030  000.030: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.165  000.135: Allocated generic buffers
000.293  000.128: locale set
000.309  000.016: GUI prepared
000.310  000.001: clipboard setup
000.336  000.026: window checked
001.009  000.673: inits 1
001.074  000.065: parsing arguments
001.076  000.002: expanding arguments
001.146  000.070: shell init
001.801  000.655: Termcap init
001.853  000.052: inits 2
002.067  000.214: init highlight
003.936  001.214  001.214: sourcing /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
. . .
019.029  001.555: loading plugins
019.137  000.108: loading packages
019.168  000.031: loading after plugins
019.192  000.024: inits 3
019.307  000.115: reading viminfo
019.309  000.002: setup clipboard
019.363  000.054: setting raw mode
019.376  000.013: start termcap
019.402  000.026: clearing screen
019.811  000.409: opening buffers
019.856  000.045: BufEnter autocommands
019.859  000.003: editing files in windows
020.005  000.146: VimEnter autocommands
020.008  000.003: before starting main loop
020.390  000.382: first screen update
020.391  000.001: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

I connect to this system using `ssh -X -t` and generally use gvim to display the editing window on my desktop.  When I do that on the problem host in addition to the long delay I get the message that the the child process could not open the GUI.  I have previously run gvim on this host without issue.

Both hosts' /etc/ssh/sshd_config file are identical save for the Listen address.  Yhe X11 entries in each are listed below:

```
grep -in x11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
102:#X11Forwarding yes
103:#X11DisplayOffset 10
104:#X11UseLocalhost yes
147:# To allow ssh tunneling in jails set X11UseLocalhost to NO
148:X11UseLocalhost no
174:#   X11Forwarding no
```

I have an identically configured host (hardware, OS, sshd_config) that I also connect to via `ssh -X -t` where this problem does not occur.  I have tried removing and reinstalling vim on the problem host, which makes no difference.

Likewise I removed the .vim directory and .viminfo file from the user's home directory.  This had no effect on startup time.  This issue is not confined to a single userid in any case.

A debugging log (`vim -V9vim_startup_debug.log`) contains this:

```
. . .
Searching for "/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/root/.vim/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
not found in 'runtimepath': "plugin/**/*.vim"
Reading viminfo file "/root/.viminfo" info oldfiles
Opening the X display failed
Executing BufEnter Autocommands for "*"
autocommand sil call s:LocalBrowse(expand("<amatch>"))
. . .
```

I am open to suggestions as to how to resolve this problem.  It is evident that X11 forwarding is somehow involved and that the clipboard setup is where the problem is happening, but I have no idea how to discover what the actual problem is.

Comment: Try to troubleshoot that using `xclip` perhaps? `time zclip -o` and `time xclip -selection clipboard -o` to read the clipboard contents from your X server... Is it possible that you have very large contents in your clipboard and the problem host is on a slower network or one with higher latency? What does `:set clipboard?` return on this host and on other hosts that do not have this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about FreeBSD and its user applications should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the question does not belong here then can a moderator move it to the appropriate forum.  However, I searched for this issue before posting and discovered that this forum has 24,959 results for `vim` vs. 1554 on unix, 758 results for `vim slow` vs. 61 results on unix, and 10 results for `vim slow x11` vs. 3 on unix.    Why my question is deemed out of place escapes me.

Comment: @ filbranden
H5 set clipboard?: clipboard=autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux

H6 set clipboard?: clipboard=autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux

Comment: @Rob or [vi.se]?

Comment: That would be a good place for this question. Note that, just because you can find such questions from the past, doesn't mean they are allowed. Some rules have changed over the years. Some people just haven't been caught yet. There are only so many of us monitoring this and we're typing as fast as we can.